# Looped array not giving the desired result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, foreach

I am writing a script that takes information from one table (release_dates), but also takes a list of X number of screen shots from a different table (release_screenshots). It then puts all the info into an array and encodes it as JSON.

However, each JSON entry has exactly the same list of screen shots.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['game_title'] = $row['game_title'];
    $row_array['game_platform'] = $row['game_platform'];
    $row_array['game_genre'] = $row['game_genre'];
    $row_array['game_publisher'] = $row['game_publisher'];
    $row_array['release_eu'] = $row['release_eu'];
    $row_array['release_us'] = $row['release_us'];
    $row_array['rrp_gbp'] = $row['rrp_gbp'];
    $row_array['rrp_eur'] = $row['rrp_eur'];
    $row_array['rrp_usd'] = $row['rrp_usd'];
    $row_array['link_address'] = $row['link_address'];
    $row_array['logo_image'] = $row['logo_image'];
    $row_array['box_art'] = $row['box_art'];

    //Build incrementing variable name
    $ssno = 1;
    $ss = "ss_".$ssno;

    //Get the list of screenshots where the referring ID is = to the current ID
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM release_screenshots WHERE parent_id = '$row_array[id]'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        $array[] = $row2;
    }

    //Add each Screenshot link to the array build and increment the variable name
    foreach($array as $x){

        $row_array[$ss] = $x['link'];
        $ssno = $ssno + 1;
        $ss = "ss_".$ssno;
    }

    $row_array['youtube_link'] = $row['youtube_link'];
    $row_array['notes'] = $row['notes'];
    $row_array['entry_created'] = $row['entry_created'];


    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

[image: Tables]

I hope I have explained this well enough. If not, I can give further information.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of two queries, do a single query that joins both tables.

Comment: ... yes, with one query you'll save time (speed up your page). but can you please provide "SHOW CREATE TABLE release_screenshot" or clarify the meaning of "parent_id" filed in human words?

Comment: @Barmar - I am quite new to MYSQL and PHP. I know what joining tables is, but I don't know how to achieve what I am trying to achieve by joining tables.

Comment: @v.sheldeshov "parent_id" is the name of a column in the release_screenshots table. It is used to reference the id of the entry that the screenshot belongs to. see: http://imgur.com/suVHv9Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear `$array` before the second `while` loop. Otherwise, you're adding to the array from the previous game.

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM release_screenshots WHERE parent_id = '$row_array[id]'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$array = array();
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $array[] = $row2;
}
```

You also need to clear `$row_array` at the beginning of the outer `while` loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array = array();
    ...
```

Comment: Great point! However, I am still getting the same result after adding the line "$array = array();" in this place.

Comment: You also need to reset `$row_array`.